# Insert float value into table with C

Tags: c, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert a float value into my table "measurements" in column "thera0"

Can someone help me?

I'm beginner, don't be too hard :D

This is my  first try error code

```
passing argument 5 of ‘PQexecParams’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
PGresult *res_values = PQexecParams(conn, "INSERT INTO measurements(theta0) VALUES($1)",1,NULL,buffer_theta0,NULL,NULL,0);
                   char*                                                                                                        
 expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
            const char *const *paramValues,
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

And this is my second try error code

memory access error

```
 float theta = 0.2;
 char buffer_theta0[10];
 sprintf(buffer_theta0,"%f",theta);
 PGresult *res_values = PQexecParams(conn, "INSERT INTO measurements(theta0) VALUES($1)",1,NULL,buffer_theta0,NULL,NULL,0);
```

```
float theta = 0.2;
char buffer_theta0[10];
sprintf(buffer_theta0,"%f",theta);
const char * const paran[]= {buffer_theta0};
PGresult *res_values = PQexecParams(conn, "INSERT INTO measurements(theta0) VALUES($1)",1,NULL,paran,NULL,NULL,0);
```

Comment: There isn't much to go on, but the buffer is miserably small. Make it large enough to accommodate any value, such as `FLT_MAX` which will need to be, say, `char buffer_theta0[64];`

Comment: Checking the [prototype of PQexecParams()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html) your first try is wrong, just as the compiler reported. Your second try fixes that problem, so you have made progress. Unfortunately,  I'm not spotting anything in your post as to what your new problem is. Have you reproduced this problem from just this code, or could other code be involved? Have you verified that your connection was successfully opened?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help, more information is needed to reproduce the problem.
See comments inline for explanations.

Good luck!

[See this discussion of how to use C to program prepared statements](https://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlc/)

> The PQexecParams function creates a prepared statement and executes it. The second parameter is the SQL statement. The third parameter is the number of parameters passed. Passing NULL to the fourth parameter means that the server should figure out the parameter types. The fifth parameter is a pointer to an array of strings containing parameters. The next two parameters are only relevant with binary parameters. Passing 0 to the final parameter we obtain result in text format, 1 in binary format.

```
gcc -I /usr/local/opt/libpq/include main.c -L /usr/local/opt/libpq/lib -lpq
./a.out
1 'Audi' 52642 0.52642
2 'Mercedes' 57127 0.57127
3 'Skoda' 9000 0.9
4 'Volvo' 29000 0.29
5 'Bentley' 350000 0.35
6 'Citroen' 21000 0.21
7 'Hummer' 41400 0.414
8 'Volkswagen' 21600 0.216
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

void do_exit(PGconn *conn, PGresult *res) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));    
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);    
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    // Data structure to hold the data going into the database
    // using a variety of incoming data types, text, integer, and float
    struct rawdata {
      char* name;
      int   value;
      float megaValue;
    };

    // These are the values to be inserted into the measurements table
    struct rawdata rawtable [] =
    {
      { "Audi"       ,  52642 , 0.52642 },
      { "Mercedes"   ,  57127 , 0.57127 },
      { "Skoda"      ,   9000 ,     0.9 },
      { "Volvo"      ,  29000 ,    0.29 },
      { "Bentley"    , 350000 ,    0.35 },
      { "Citroen"    ,  21000 ,    0.21 },
      { "Hummer"     ,  41400 ,   0.414 },
      { "Volkswagen" ,  21600 ,   0.216 }
    };
    
    // Here is the database connection being used
    PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb("user=atl dbname=nameofdatabase");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQfinish(conn);
        exit(1);
    }

    // To be more helpful to others, create the table in each example
    // this allows everyone to see the table format and how it was created
    // sometimes the error is in the way tables are created
    PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS measurements");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) { do_exit(conn, res); }
    PQclear(res);
    res = PQexec(conn, "CREATE TABLE measurements ( measure_id serial PRIMARY KEY, col1 text, col2 integer, col3 float );" );
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) { do_exit(conn, res); }
    PQclear(res);

    // This is related to the ask about how to insert values into a table using PQexecParams
    // This is the string that specifies the command and the params
    char *sinto = "INSERT INTO measurements VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)";

    // This is the loop to change the params on each row (and provide a unique ID)
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(rawtable) / sizeof(rawtable[0]); i++)
    {
        // creating storage for params, not the best way (works though)
        char p1[100], p2[100], p3[100], p4[100];

        // prepare param input array by initializing array to params
        const char *paramValues[] = { p1, p2, p3, p4 };

        // initialize params for this iteration
        sprintf( p1, "%d", i+1 );                      // key
        sprintf( p2, "'%s'", rawtable[i].name );       // text
        sprintf( p3, "%d", rawtable[i].value );        // integer
        sprintf( p4, "%0.6f", rawtable[i].megaValue ); // float

        // make call to database server
        res = PQexecParams(conn, sinto, 4, NULL, paramValues, NULL, NULL, 0);
        if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) 
            do_exit(conn, res);     
        PQclear(res);    
    }
    
    // display results
    res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM measurements");    
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        printf("No data retrieved\n");        
        PQclear(res);
        do_exit(conn, res);
    }    
    int rows = PQntuples(res);
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", PQgetvalue(res, i, 0), PQgetvalue(res, i, 1), PQgetvalue(res, i, 2), PQgetvalue(res, i, 3));
    }    
    PQclear(res);  
    PQfinish(conn);

    return 0;
}
```